# RAPIDS installation issue

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, rapids

I have executed the pip install commands from RAPIDS into Google Colab ipynb jupyter notebook. They are:

```
pip install cudf-cu11 dask-cudf-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
pip install cuml-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
pip install cugraph-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
```

Machine assigned by Colab:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    26W /  70W |      0MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Error when execute every single (and separated) pip install:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting cudf-cu11
  Using cached cudf_cu11-23.2.0.tar.gz (6.5 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Should obtain something like that but i didn't reach it

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue which started on Friday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
!pip install cudf-cu11==22.12 rmm-cu11==22.12 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/.
```

Source:
https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/12762#issuecomment-1427064693

Answer (score 1):

I worked on solving this the for 2 days straight and I guess I had something to work. I am using a different version to install cudf, cuml, cugraph. I tried this on google colab btw!

```
pip install dask==2022.9.2 distributed==2022.9.2 ucx-py-cu11==0.29.0 cudf-cu11==22.10 rmm-cu11==22.10 dask-cudf-cu11==22.10 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
pip install dask==2022.9.2 distributed==2022.9.2 ucx-py-cu11==0.29.0 raft-dask-cu11==22.10 pylibcugraph-cu11==22.10 pylibraft-cu11==22.10 cuml-cu11==22.10 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
pip install dask==2022.9.2 distributed==2022.9.2 ucx-py-cu11==0.29.0 raft-dask-cu11==22.10 pylibcugraph-cu11==22.10 pylibraft-cu11==22.10 cudf-cu11==22.10 cugraph-cu11==22.10 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
pip uninstall cupy-cuda115 -y
pip uninstall cupy-cuda11x -y
pip install cupy-cuda11x -f https://pip.cupy.dev/aarch64
pip install nvidia-ml-py3
```

Also check the comment on [rapids github repo issue](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/12762#issuecomment-1462657683)